# How to correctly interpret NuPIC output

Tags: nupic

This is output snippet of one step ahead prediction:

```
order,original,prediction,anomaly score
175,0,0.0,0.32500000000000001
176,62,52.0,0.65000000000000002
177,402,0.0,1.0
178,0,0.0,0.125
179,402,0.0,1.0
180,0,0.0,0.0
181,3,402.0,0.050000000000000003
182,50,52.0,0.10000000000000001
183,68,13.0,0.90000000000000002
```

Three questions:

1. If this is one step ahead prediction then the prediction value on
   line n should correspond to the original value on line n+1 
   (assuming that NuPIC made good prediction and not mistake)?
2. If first question is true can you please explain me the 179 line? On
   line 179 there is prediction which equals 0 and on line 180 original
   value equals to 0 which is OK. But why I get anomaly score 1 on line
   179?
3. Or you can look at it vice versa: Prediction on line 180 is equal to
   0 but the original value on line 181 is 3. So I assume prediction
   was wrong. Why anomaly score on line 180 equals to 0? Does it means
   that NuPIC believe that it is predicting the correct value but in
   fact it was wrong?

How should I interpret this?